# Try to showing product file size on product single page

Tags: single

i have new site for freebies so all people can download file direct on my site. I'm using woocommerce to share these file, and now i want to showing file size on my single product page. This my code:

```
<?php
    if ( ! empty( $downloadable_files ) ) {
        foreach ( $downloadable_files as $files ) {
            foreach ( $files as $file ) {

                $downloads = $product->get_files();
                foreach( $downloads as $key => $each_download ) {

                    $path = str_replace( site_url('/'), ABSPATH, esc_url($each_download["file"]) );

                    if (!empty($file['name'])) {
                        echo '<li class="nitro-line"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o mgr10"></i>'.esc_html($file['name'] ).'&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;'.size_format(filesize($path)).'</li>';
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

the output like this:

```
example.zip  -  50MB
```

This code work perfect on localhost, but if i try to my server this code not work. If online only showing file name not with filesize. Are my code worng, can you correct it? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Right after you set the `$path` variable, echo it in an html comment - `?><!--
 <?php echo $path; ?> --><?php` - so you can confirm whether or not it's the right path to the file. If you're using a CDN, maybe it's the wrong path?

Comment: i not using CDN and i think the `$path` not wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Change from:

```
$path = str_replace( site_url('/'), ABSPATH, esc_url($each_download["file"]) );
```

to:

```
$ProductID = attachment_url_to_postid( $each_download["file"] );
$path = get_attached_file( $ProductID );
```

And now work perfect...